# Why isn't the maximum argument of this loci pi/2?

Tags: complex-numbers

[image]

[image]

Why isn't the maximum argument $-\pi/2$ ? Where it is tangential to the imaginary axis as this seems a larger argument that -0.330?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maximum argument means largest (most positive).

Clearly $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ is the **minimum** argument, not the maximum as it is the most negative, and hence the smallest.

Comment: Ah okay, I was thinking of the magnitude of the argument mostly, if that makes sense.Thank you.